# How to Download base64 image using DownloadManager?

Tags: android, android-download-manager

How to Download base64 image using DownloadManager (I mean image must to show in application Downloads after download(convert base64 to bytes and save in file) )

For example: 
I need load image from my custom browser from next html `"<img src=\"data:image/jpeg;base64,someBase64String" />"`. And load it exactly same(for user opinion) as a normal image url. For normal image url I use DownloadManager:

```
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(source);
        request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, fileName);
        request.setTitle(fileName);
        request.setDescription(fileName);
        DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) App.getInstance().getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        dm.enqueue(request);
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) App.getInstance().getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        String[] fileNameAndExt = getFileNameAndExt(file.getName());
        dm.addCompletedDownload(fileNameAndExt[0], file.getName(), true, "image/" + fileNameAndExt[1], file.getPath(), file.length(), true);
```

Also need permission in Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

It is strange, but other side it not worked.